# sed remove match and next lines

Tags: sed

Not sure why my RedGex expression not working, I'm trying to ommit match and next lines

```
[example.com]
10.0.0.1 
10.0.0.2
[example.net]
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20
```

Desired output

```
[example.net]
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20
```

Here is what I have tried so far, but it matches more lines than desired

```
   sed -e '/(\[example.com\])(.*\n)+/d'
```

Comment: is the number of lines to delete after matching `[example.com]` fixed or variable?

Comment: number of lines is variable :)

Comment: so, you want to delete from line matching `[example.com]` upto but not including next line matching `[example.*]`?

Comment: You are correct, [example.com] and following lines should be deleted, however [example.net] should remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for every desirable attribute of software (efficiency, clarity, robustness, portability, maintainability, etc., etc.):

```
$ awk '/^\[/{f=/\[example\.com\]/} f' file
[example.com]
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2

$ awk '/^\[/{f=/\[example\.com\]/} !f' file
[example.net]
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `awk` is more suited for this task

```
$ awk '/\[example.com\]/{f=1; next} /\[example.*\]/{f=0} !f' ip.txt 
[example.net]
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20
```

- `/\[example.com\]/{f=1; next}` if line matches `[example.com]` set a flag `f` and move on to next line
- `/\[example.*\]/{f=0}` if line matches `\[example.*\]`, unset the flag
- `!f` print lines if flag is not set

With `sed`, the best I could do is using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978201/4082052)

```
$ sed '/\[example.com\]/,/\[example.*\]/ { /\[example.com\]/d; /\[example.*\]/!d }' ip.txt 
[example.net]
10.0.0.10
10.0.0.20
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\[[^]*\]/h;G;/\n\[example.com\]/!P;d' file
```

On encountering a line(s) you don't want to match, store said line in the hold space (HS), append it to the pattern space (PS) and only print current line if the second part does not contain the required string.